# How to set the title for the icon at the bottom on swipe right?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display the title at the bottom of the icon on swipe right of the tableViewCell. I am writing the code for that cell like this

```
let moreBtnRight : MGSwipeButton = 
    MGSwipeButton(title: "More",icon:UIImage(named: "New menu_icon"),
    backgroundColor:UIColor(red: 235/255.0,green: 94/255.0, blue: 26/255.0, alpha: 0.9));
let emailBtnRight : MGSwipeButton = 
    MGSwipeButton(title: "EMail", icon:UIImage(named:"Swipe_Right_Email"),
    backgroundColor:UIColor(red: 235/255.0,green: 94/255.0, blue: 26/255.0, alpha: 0.9));
let messageBtnRight : MGSwipeButton = 
     MGSwipeButton(title: "SMS", icon:UIImage(named: "Swipe_Text_Right"),
     backgroundColor:UIColor(red: 235/255.0,green: 94/255.0, blue: 26/255.0, alpha: 0.9));
```

But, this code displays the title at beside of the icon.
Here is the output I am getting :

[image]

How to set the title at the bottom of the icon.,Please help me out? 
Advance Thanks

Comment: Please add the image to your Q.

Comment: Just a comment on those who have voted to close this question : Neither this is too broad (User has specifically mentioned what he wants - text below the icon) and neither it is unclear what he is asking (same reason as above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example. You can replace the icon and title by yours. But this is how you should do this. Use `centerIconOverText` function in the library:

```
let mail = MGSwipeButton(title: "Mail", icon: UIImage(named: "mail.png"), backgroundColor: UIColor.blue)
mail.centerIconOverText()
```

**Here is the output :**

[image]

Comment: Yeah thank you for that @nitish., but it is showing error like  "Value of MGSwipeButton has no member centerIconOverText".

Comment: Then you are probably using older version of library. I just added the above 2 lines of code and an icon in the demo project of this library - MailAppDemoSwift. On running, I got the above response.

Comment: what are the changes can i do now?

Comment: Download the latest version of library. Either through pods or manually. And replace the current version you are using in your code.

Comment: Just for try purpose, you can test this on the sample projects of this library which come along with the downloaded zip.

Comment: Thank you for the help @nitish.

Comment: Did that work ? If yes, please accept my answer for future reference.

Comment: Is there any other ways to do it? without updating the libraries. because some other classes are connect with that library.

Comment: I don't think so. Other classes will still be correct if you replace the old version with new one.

Comment: One more thing., How to reduce the icon size and title size?

Comment: I think you should have an image with smaller size. Regarding title size, need to explore a bit more on the library. You can check the issues for this library on GitHub. That might help you as well

Comment: Okay., Anyway Thank you so much.